# IIS 6 + JBoss 7 web application URL configuration

Tags: iis, jboss, jboss7.x, isapi, mod-jk

Good morning!

I successfully bound my iis 6.0 to my jboss 7 web application following tutorials like this: http://www.techstacks.com/howto/iis_and_isapi_redirect.html

I used my application before going to 192.168.1.1:8080/myapp (directly to jboss)

Now I am able to use www.mydomainwebsite.my/myapp

I'm happy enough but it would be better to have simply "www.mydomainwebsite.my" pointing to the app context without seeing "myapp" in the URL.

I tried putting in uriworkermap.properties file either: /=local And /myapp/=local

But if I visit simply www.mydomainwebsite.com I still see jboss default homepage.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to undeploy the welcome page.

In the config change `enable-welcome-root="true"` to `enable-welcome-root="false"`

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:web:1.1" default-virtual-server="default-host" native="false">
    <connector name="http" protocol="HTTP/1.1" scheme="http" socket-binding="http"/>
    <virtual-server name="default-host" enable-welcome-root="true">
        <alias name="localhost"/>
        <alias name="example.com"/>
    </virtual-server>
</subsystem>
```

Then make you web app work from the root context by setting it in the jboss-web.xml in the WEB-INF

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<jboss-web>
    <context-root>/</context-root>
</jboss-web>
```

I am not entirely sure if the last xml is well formed in respect to the xsd from jboss-as7, but should work.

Comment: THANK YOU! :) It's not easy to find this info, you're great! Only a couple of things: 1) there's a typo in your answer, it should be 'enable-welcome-root="false"'. I think you meant that.

Comment: 2) I am thinking of a production environment with dozens of web apps. What if I want to map all to their own roots? I mean: www.site1.com => /    www.site2.com => /   and so on... Is that the <alias> purpose? How does it work?

Comment: You can find the xtd for the jboss-web.xml here: https://github.com/jboss/metadata/blob/master/web/src/main/resources/schema/jboss-web_7_0.xsd. I think and I am just guessing here that you have to create virtual server in the web subsystem and then bind that with you jboss-web.xml's virtual-host definition. I highly discourage the deployment of more than one web application per jvm (i.e. per jboss instance), much more now that jboss 7 is so lightweight. This is also recommended by jboss consultants for many reasons.